# len of varbinary 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

this is a followup question to [len of varbinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661641/len-of-varbinary)

len(0x0a0b0c0d) returns 4 because len counts bytes. does this behaviour depend on the current server collation? if i chose utf-16 for example, would it return 2? in other words, does len treat its argument as string or does it distinguish parameter types and just counts bytes for binary?

i am using mssql 2005

thanks
konstantin

Comment: I think you mean [DATALENGTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx); [LEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) returns the number of characters (ignoring whitespace).

Comment: thanks, i did not know about datalength!

Answer (score 0):

collation don t affects varbinary fields and vars.